# Ideal in a ring and quotient

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring, and $I$ a proper ideal in $R$. Prove that if for every element $x$ in $R-I$, $x^2-1$ belongs to $I$, then $R/I$ is $\Bbb Z_2$ or $\Bbb Z_3$.

I know that $I$ does not contain any units, otherwise $I$ is equal to $R$, can any one help me?

Comment: Let $x\in R\setminus I$. $1\in x^2 + I$, so $1+ I = x^2 +I$, so $(x+I)(x+I) = 1+I$. So any non zero element in $R/I$ is of order $2$, and $R/I$ is a field. And the last ingredient is that if you let $K=R/I$, then $K^*$ is cyclic

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* $x^2=1$ for all nonzero $x \in K=R/I$ implies that $K$ is a field.
In a field, polynomials equations have a finite number of solutions.

Answer (score 1):

An equivalent way to state that condition is: for every nonzero element $x\in R/I$ we have $x^2=1$. In particular $R/I$ is a field.

For every nonzero $x\in R/I$ we have $0=x^2-1=(x+1)(x-1)$. Therefore, since $R/I$ is an integral domain we have $x=\pm 1$ and $R/I=\{0,1,-1\}$.

If $1=-1$ then $R/I=\mathbb{Z}_2$, otherwise $R/I=\mathbb{Z}_3$.